# How can I use SPARQL to find instances where two properties do not share any of the same objects?

Tags: sparql, rdf

In my company's taxonomy, all concepts have a value for **skos:prefLabel**, and most have a bunch of values for a custom property -- let's call it **ex:keyword** -- whose values have the datatype **rdf:langString**. I want to find concepts where the value of **skos:prefLabel** does NOT exactly match ANY value of **ex:keyword**, when case and language are ignored.

It is fairly straightforward to write a query for concepts where the values DO match, like this:

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
  ?concept skos:prefLabel ?label ;
    ex:keyword ?kw
  FILTER (lcase(str(?label)) = lcase(str(?kw)))
}
```

Where I'm getting tripped up is in trying to negate this.

Using `!=` in the FILTER would just return a bunch of cases where **?label** and **?kw** don't match, which is not what I'm after.

What I would like is to be able to use a FILTER NOT EXISTS, but that's invalid with an expression like `(?a = ?b)`; it only works with something like `{?a ?b ?c}`.

I suspect that there is a proper way to express `FILTER NOT EXISTS (?a = ?b)` in SPARQL, but I don't know what it is. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to put the triple pattern for matching the keyword in the `FILTER NOT EXISTS`, like so:

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
  ?concept skos:prefLabel ?label .
  FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?concept ex:keyword ?kw .
                      FILTER(lcase(str(?label)) = lcase(str(?kw))) 
                    }
}
```

This query says "I want all concepts with a preflabel such that the concept has no keyword value that matches that prefLabel".